# Flutter: Cannot change AppBar's title color with AppBarTheme

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a custom theme to control my app's theme, and among other things, I have colors set for my app bar.

Although the background color is set as expected, the font color doesn't get set. What's the reason?

Also, is this the correct way to set a theme? I'll be extending the theme later, so I want everything to be as modular as possible.

```dart
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_that/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:note_that/theme/theme.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const NoteThat());
}

class NoteThat extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoteThat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "NoteThat",
      theme: ThemeCustom.getThemeData(), // <-- Setting theme here
      routes: {"/": (context) => const HomePage()},
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
// /theme/theme.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class ThemeCustom {
  static const Color _primaryColor = Color.fromRGBO(7, 91, 154, 255);

  static ThemeData getThemeData() {
    return ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: _primaryColor), // <-- Setting title text color here
            backgroundColor: Colors.white),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
            titleLarge: GoogleFonts.montserrat(),
            titleMedium: GoogleFonts.lato(),
            titleSmall: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            bodyLarge: GoogleFonts.lato(),
            bodyMedium: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            bodySmall: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            labelLarge: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            labelSmall: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: _primaryColor));
  }
}
```

```dart
// /pages/home.dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle, // <-- Accessing title text color here
        title: const Text("NoteThat"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide themeData with provider package, so I can control dark mode and light mode in application, if you want to change Theme(dark and light), how do you plan to do it the way you did it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isLighTheme = false;

  void changeTheme() {
    isLighTheme = !isLighTheme;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ThemeData get currentTheme =>
      isLighTheme ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark();
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider(create: (_) => ResourceContext()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(create: (context) =>ThemeNotifier()) 
    ],
    builder: (context, child) => const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget with NavigatorCustom {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: context.watch<ThemeNotifier>().currentTheme,
      onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return const LottieLearn(); 
        });
      },
      onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
      navigatorKey: NavigatorManager.instance.navigatorGlobalKey,
      home: const LoginView(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(theme: ThemeCustom.getThemeData(), title: 'Material App', home: const HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle, // <-- Accessing title text color here
        title: const Text("NoteThat"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeCustom {
  static const Color _primaryColor = Colors.black;

  static ThemeData getThemeData() {
    return ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: _primaryColor,
            ), // <-- Setting title text color here
            backgroundColor: Colors.white),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: _primaryColor));
  }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was asking. I was asking why can I not change AppBar's title text's color through AppTheme whereas I can do the same for background color?

Comment: mybad, If I change _primaryColor I can see my AppBar's title text's color change, try this code, I updated, this is what you asking for ?